# How to make NSMutableAttributedString responsive with dynamic type text from settings app

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, nsattributedstring, dynamic-type-feature

```
let dictTitleColor = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.LTColor()]
let titleAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: dictTitleColor)
alert.setValue(titleAttributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

When I Increase the font size of the device the title string dont increase i have set this string in alertview controller ? So How to make This Responsive to font size Change ?

Answer (score 3):

```
let dictTitleColor = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.green,
                      NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)]
let titleAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: dictTitleColor)
alert.setValue(titleAttributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
```

**NOTE:** This will fail if the popup is presented and then user changed the font size in the accessibility settings. For this case you might need to listen to the [`UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontentsizecategory/1622948-didchangenotification) and update the font size there.

e.g.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(preferredContentSizeChanged(_:)), name: UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

The method

```
@objc func preferredContentSizeChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
  let dictTitleColor = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.green,
                        NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)]
  let titleAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: title, attributes: dictTitleColor)
  alert.setValue(titleAttributedString, forKey: "attributedTitle")
}
```

Comment: Setting .Headline Font Will Change The Default Font . What Is The Default Font for AttributedString ?

Comment: I don't know what's the default but if I've to guess then it would be `UIFont.systemFont`

Comment: If i set at  function  preferredContentSizeChanged new alert would popup above the old one !

Comment: You don't have to show the alert again, just change the font size of the existing alert

Comment: If alert is already Opened and user change the font size the above code wouldn't work .

Comment: Did you hold the reference of the alert shown? and did your callback is being called?

Comment: how to hold reference of the alert shown would be a great help if you can demonstrate it using code !.

Comment: Since Swift 4.2 some notification names has changed. Use 'UIContentSizeCategory.didChangeNotification' instead of 'NSNotification.Name.UIContentSizeCategoryDidChange'.

Answer (score 1):

To adapt dynamic font size and enable accessibility for attributed text you can use the following function.

```
static func convertHtml(string: String?) -> NSAttributedString? {
    
    guard let string = string else {return nil}
    
    guard let data = string.data(using: .utf8) else {
        return nil
    }
    
    do {
        let attrStr = try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                      options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                      documentAttributes: nil)
        let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attrStr.length)
        let str = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: attrStr)
        
        str.enumerateAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font, in: NSMakeRange(0, str.length), options: .longestEffectiveRangeNotRequired) {
            (value, range, stop) in
            if let font = value as? UIFont {
                
                let userFont =  UIFontDescriptor.preferredFontDescriptor(withTextStyle: .title2)
                let pointSize = userFont.withSize(font.pointSize)
                let customFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: pointSize.pointSize)
                let dynamicText = UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: customFont)
                str.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.font,
                                         value: dynamicText,
                                         range: range)
            }
        }

        str.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle, value: 0, range: range)
        
        return NSAttributedString(attributedString: str.attributedSubstring(from: range))
    } catch {}
    return nil
    
}
```

Then you can you this on ur textview.

```
let htmToStringText = convertHtml(string: html))
            
  self.bodyTextView.isEditable = false
  self.bodyTextView.isAccessibilityElement = true
  self.bodyTextView.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
  self.bodyTextView.attributedText = htmToStringText
  self.bodyTextView.accessibilityAttributedLabel = htmToStringText
```